# Jira Rest API is slow

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

So I'm using Jira Rest API, where the user can type their own JQL query and then a table will display tasks. The only problem is my Rest API is very slow, and I think it's due to login before it can access the data. Is there a way to make the Rest API faster?

a simple call which GETs around 20 task results takes up to 17sec, before the user gets the requested information.

the URL can be something like:

```
https://jirabd.xxx.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%20in%20(BUG%2CFIELDB)%20AND%20component%20in%20(%22Fieldb%20Components%22)%20%22AND%20issuetype%20=%20BUG%20AND%20status%20!=%20%22Closed%22&fields=customfield_10100,customfield_10101,status
```

I simply just need to know where I might have to look to boost the performance, since I have no clue how/where to start looking.

**EDIT**

Did some more digging regarding login, and it seems its the way our accounts has been setup in the company. The service account I use for login, takes 17sec to login, where a regular account takes 1-2sec to login, so that's why. Now I just have to figure out why this is the case.

Comment: It seems some reverse proxy related issues going on. Are you using nginx or Apache for proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is login, try keeping the authentication cookie for the next requests:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/cookie-based-authentication/
or OAuth as they do suggest